# My checkout page gets blank

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I'm using credit card, in my logs I get the error `Transaction declined`, but I don't see a blank page in front end. I want that errors appear in front end, at least a redirection to checkout page showing that errors. how can I do that ?

Comment: I think you are not throw any exception for error. try to write catch exception. catch error and force redirect to checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the errors, go to your `index.php` replace `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

**EDIT:**

Maybe you have an error in the code which makes that page blank, Or you have installed an extension that does this bug, try to compare it with this one

**Path:** `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage.phtml`

**Content:**

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?></span>
            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
        <div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var accordion = new Accordion('checkoutSteps', '.step-title', true);
    <?php if($this->getActiveStep()): ?>
    accordion.openSection('opc-<?php echo $this->getActiveStep() ?>');
    <?php endif ?>
    var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
        progress: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
        review: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
        saveMethod: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
        failure: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
    );
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I've enable that, but nothings happend, In my logs appear..  Transaction declined. but I dont know why it is not showed in front end, and nothing more else happend, just blank page

Comment: Please look my update

Comment: is the same, I'm using Magestore OneStepCheckout extension, it 's in conflict with other apparently. I just added a redirection. to previous page., thanks for the help.